# Create Dynamic Section MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to render a data driven Bootstrap Carousel in an `@section` within MVC.

I want to render the section on my `_LayoutPage` which I do with this:

```
    <div class="blurred-container">
        @RenderSection("headerBlob",true)
    </div>
```

But it seems that it creates the carousel before the app retrieves the image URL's from the API. 
Here is the `@section` that I create

```
 @section headerBlob {

    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/core")
    @*scripts/core contans jQuery and bootstrapjs*@

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //gets last segment of URL
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("#") > -1) {

        } else {
            var segment_str = window.location.pathname;
            var segment_array = segment_str.split('/');
            var last_segment = segment_array[segment_array.length - 1];
        }

        //Get's Image's Based on URL Identifier 
        $.getJSON('/API/VehicleImage?u=' + last_segment, function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                //The Console is for Debug, and It DOES return the Image URLs
                console.log(data[i].VehicleImageURL);
                //Should create the div based on the image URL
                $('#itms').html('<div class="item"><img src="' + data[i].VehicleImageURL + '" class="img-responsive"></div>');
            };
        });
    </script>
    <!-- main slider carousel -->
    <div class="row">
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- main slider carousel items -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" id="itms">
                <!-- SHOULD DYNAMICALLY CREATE IMAGES to DISPLAY -->
            </div>
            <!-- main slider carousel nav controls -->
            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                <span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/main slider carousel-->
}
```

here is the screen cap to show the URL's being retrieved (all the URL's are valid)
 [image: Debug From Console.log]
And here is a screen cap of the elements after rendering
[image: After the page has loaded, the elements generated]

ANY advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this you have to surround your `jQuery` code with `$(document).ready`. In this way your `#itms` will be populated with image after the DOM is created.

You **replace the content** of `itms` because you make use of `html` and you need to use [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to **append all** images.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//gets last segment of URL
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("#") > -1) {

    } else {
        var segment_str = window.location.pathname;
        var segment_array = segment_str.split('/');
        var last_segment = segment_array[segment_array.length - 1];
    }

    //Get's Image's Based on URL Identifier 
    $.getJSON('/API/VehicleImage?u=' + last_segment, function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            //The Console is for Debug, and It DOES return the Image URLs
            console.log(data[i].VehicleImageURL);
            //Should create the div based on the image URL
            $('#itms').append('<div class="item"><img src="' + data[i].VehicleImageURL + '" class="img-responsive"></div>');
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried that, same result as before. I'm not sure but I think it creates that section before it has time to finish the the getJSON method for the images..

Comment: @JacquesBronkhorst The DOM must generate first, that `div` with `id="itms"` to exist when `getJSON` is called. The `section` is generated server side and the client will get the entire page at once. You can also try to move at the end of the `section` the code.

Comment: @JacquesBronkhorst i spotted your problem, you make use of `html` instead of `append`. Also, don't forget to keep `(document).ready`.

Comment: YOU SIR! have solved the issue of generating the data, but now it just doesn't display the image, but it does create the elements.

Comment: @JacquesBronkhorst if you navigate to that `url` you can see the image?

Comment: yes the image URL does redirect to the correct image. I have changed the class of 'item' to `<div class="item active">` , then it shows all the images